# Swift UIView resizing it's frame without any input

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiview, swift4

I am trying to create an application that mimics the behavior of the cards in the AppStore. My current method of doing this is to create a copy of the collection view cell's (a custom UIView I load into the cell) as it is selected, add it to the view in the exact same frame as the cell, and expand it from there. However, even though I am able to assign the correct frame to the view, sometime after "didSelectItemAt" is completed, the view changes its frame to origin (0,0) and the minimum width&height to fit its content.

One thing interesting I noticed is that I am able to animate it and see it moving from the intended origin to (0,0). This is if I use UIView.animate for a few seconds (or use CMD-T for slow animations) and insert self.view.layoutSubviews() in the animation block.

```
    var currentView:AirportView?

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? AirportCollectionViewCell {
            whiteView.alpha = 0.3

            currentView = .get()
            self.view.addSubview(currentView!)
            currentView!.frame = self.view.convert(cell.frame, from: self.collectionView)
            print("Relative     frame is \(self.view.convert(cell.frame, from: self.collectionView))")
            print("Current view frame is \(currentView!.frame)")
        }
    }

    @objc func reset(_ sender: UIView) {
        print("Reset cview frame is \(currentView!.frame)")
        whiteView.alpha = 0
        currentView?.removeFromSuperview()
        currentView = nil
        self.collectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
    }
```

Here is the output from the print statements:

```
Relative     frame is (0.0, 136.0, 375.0, 415.0)
Current view frame is (0.0, 136.0, 375.0, 415.0)
Reset cview  frame is (0.0, 0.0, 323.6666666666667, 458.6666666666667)
```

If I call self.view.layoutSubviews() immediately after assigning the new frame, the output is:

```
Relative     frame is (0.0, 136.0, 375.0, 415.0)
Current view frame is (0.0, 0.0, 323.6666666666667, 414.6666666666667)
Reset cview  frame is (0.0, 0.0, 323.6666666666667, 458.6666666666667)
```

So I assume the view is laying out subviews somewhere behind the scenes, but I'm not sure why that would change the frame of currentView.

Any advice would be appreciated, this has been driving me mad all day.

Comment: Are you using Autolayout and constraints?  If so, then you shouldn't manipulate the `frame` - You should change the `constant` of the relevant constraint.

Comment: @Paulw11the innards of currentView are contained in a stackview that is constrained to the view, but as far as adding a fresh version of it to self.view, all I am doing is programmatic and done in the code I provided